# Unable to resolve path to module in nextJS app using module deferation plugin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js, webpack-module-federation

I'm working with the `module-federation/nextjs-mf` webpack [plugin](https://app.privjs.com/buy/packageDetail?pkg=@module-federation/nextjs-mf), which allow us to work with micro-frontned architecture.

According with the official documentation and based on [this example](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/react-nextjs/nextjs-host-remote), we can share components between the remote and host app.

The above example works great using only out of the box nextjs code.

Actually I'm trying to achieve this, a host app and `n` remote apps all of them using:

- NextJS
- `module-federation/nextjs-mf` plugin
- TypeScript

[image]

As you can see I'm working with more than 2 nextjs apps, the remotes apps can share components successfully, but, the host app is breaking due to this error:

[image]

Its implementation:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
const NextRemoteComponent = dynamic(
  () => import("remote_finances/next-remote-component"),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

Unlike the rest of the apps, this `host` app is using a "different" `next.config.js` configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack5: true,
  webpack(config, options) {
    const { webpack, isServer } = options;
    config.experiments = { topLevelAwait: true };

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /_app.js/,
      loader: '@module-federation/nextjs-mf/lib/federation-loader.js',
    });

    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.container.ModuleFederationPlugin({
        remotes: {
          remote_finances: "remote_finances@http://localhost:8081/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js",
          remote: 'remote@http://localhost:8081/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
        },
        shared: {
          react: {
            singleton: true,
            eager: true,
            requiredVersion: false,
          },
        },
      }),
    );
    return config;
  },
  // nextJS config
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true
  },
  env: {
    BASE_URL : `https://qa-core-api.nordhen.com`,
  },
};
```

I tryed almost everthing, changed and tryed many `.eslintrc`-`.eslintrc.json` configurations, packages, and don't know exactly if it's due to:

- Typescript
- Lint
- Webpack

If you need any extra information about the code or its implementation you can ask.
Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bypass eslint (and if you are using vs code) with this two lines.

It worked for me.

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
const NextRemoteComponent = dynamic(
  // @ts-ignore
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  () => import("remote_finances/next-remote-component"),
  { ssr: false }
)
```